# About Android Emulator Error

Tags: android-emulator

Output:

> Hax is enabled Hax ram_size 0x60000000 HAX is working and emulator
>   runs in fast virt mode. emulator: Listening for console connections on
>   port: 5554 emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB):
>   emulator-5554 emulator: WARNING:
>   ./android/metrics/metrics_reporter_toolbar.cpp:189: Can't upload usage
>   metrics: Error

I opened the Android Emulator just appear this ERROR.
why? My application can run unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

that's not a system problem, just a google usage statistics;

you can :
Open the Android Studio->Preferences, go to Appearance & Behavior->System Settings->Usage Statistics, and uncheck "Send usage statistics to Google". Now the matrics_reporter will be disabled during emulator starting. 
then restart emulator, problem gone;